# Electron - Cannot run application on Ubuntu 64-bit

Tags: executable, electron

I have an executable file, that I create using [Electron Packager](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager), named "SteamCMD GUI".
When I attempt to double-click it, it won't execute, but Ubuntu tries to execute it using [PyPar2](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/pypar2/).
Next, I typed in the terminal:

```
file SteamCMD\ GUI
```

Then I got the following:

```
SteamCMD GUI: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.26, BuildID[sha1]=8e66ed87010d0cb4ed7d7926d2dc454ea2561b5c, stripped
```

Which made me think that I can indeed execute the file, so I typed:

```
bash SteamCMD\ GUI
```

But, then I got the following error:

```
SteamCMD GUI: SteamCMD GUI: cannot execute binary file
```

How to solve this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: `bash` is for running shell scripts, not binary executables. Either place the file somewhere that's on your `PATH`, or provide a path to it (if the file is in the current directory, that's as simple as typing `./` before the name e.g. `./SteamCMD\ GUI`)

Comment: Thanks for replying! When typing `bash ./SteamCMD\ GUI`, I get `./SteamCMD GUI: ./SteamCMD GUI: cannot execute binary file`

Comment: It seems I wasn't clear. Do **not** type `bash` at all - **just** `./SteamCMD\ GUI`

Comment: Oh nice, that worked. Is there a way to launch it by double-clicking it instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I simply needed to give the executable the permissions it needed, so I typed in the terminal:

```
chmod +x SteamCMD\ GUI
```

And then everything worked perfectly - I could both execute it by double-clicking it, and by typing to the terminal `./SteamCMD\ GUI`.

Answer (score 0):

@steeldriver and @avi12 your answer worked for me as well. Thanks!

I am running Ubuntu 16.04LTS and added a script in my `package.json` so that I could run `npm run package-linux` from my source directory in terminal. The script in my `package.json` was

`"package-linux": "electron-packager . electroyarn-app --overwrite --asar=true --platform=linux --arch=x64 --prune=true --out=release-builds"`